# Finding children of a specific parent tag in XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

So I have an XML file that looks somewhat like this:

```
<root>
   <BillingAddress>
      <AddressType>Billing</AddressType>
      <StreetName>SomeStreet</StreetName>
      <HouseNumber>234</HouseNumber>
      <PostCode>6436</PostCode>
      <PostalPlace>TOWN</PostalPlace>
      <CountryCode>CA</CountryCode>
    </BillingAddress>
    <DeliveryAddress>
      <AddressType>Delivery</AddressType>
      <StreetName>Street</StreetName>
      <HouseNumber>666</HouseNumber>
      <PostCode>432</PostCode>
      <PostalPlace>CITY</PostalPlace>
      <CountryCode>CO</CountryCode>
     </DeliveryAddress>
</root>
```

This file has several elements with the same name, AddressType, StreetName etc. What I would like is to retrieve only the values found inside the BillingAddress parent and not the DeliveryAddress. I have tried something like this `XElement streetName = xmlDocument.Descendants("BillingAddress").First(p => p.Name.LocalName == "StreetName");`, but that does not return anything. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: it's obviously because `Descendant("BillingAddress")` of `root` returns `BillingAddress` ... obviously getting elements of it should do the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var billingAddress = xmlDocument.Root.Descendants("BillingAddress");
string streetName = billingAddress.Descendants("StreetName").FirstOrDefault()?.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to get to a particular xml child:

```
        var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load("example.xml");

        XmlNode billingAddress = document["root"]["BillingAddress"];// or document.GetElementsByTagName("BillingAddress")[0]; (previous answer)

        var addressType = billingAddress["AddressType"].InnerText;
        var streetName = billingAddress["StreetName"].InnerText;
```

Comment: That's not what OP wants. They want to get a child element of BillingAddress.

Comment: OP: "What I would like is to retrieve only the values found inside the BillingAddress parent and not the DeliveryAddress."
And I think my code does exactly that.

Comment: The keyword here is 'inside'.

Answer (score 0):

A totally different approach is to use `XmlSerializer`.  For this you would need to define a class that maps your `XML`.  For example:

```
[XmlRoot]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement]
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public Address DeliveryAddress { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string StreetName{ get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string PostalPlace { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

You can now deserialize the `XML` with code like this:

```
string xml = "<Root><BillingAddress><AddressType>Billing</AddressType><StreetName>SomeStreet</StreetName><HouseNumber>234</HouseNumber><PostCode>6436</PostCode><PostalPlace>TOWN</PostalPlace><CountryCode>CA</CountryCode></BillingAddress><DeliveryAddress><AddressType>Delivery</AddressType><StreetName>Street</StreetName><HouseNumber>666</HouseNumber><PostCode>432</PostCode><PostalPlace>CITY</PostalPlace><CountryCode>CO</CountryCode></DeliveryAddress></Root>";
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
var r = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
```

This now enables you to access the values so:

```
string streetName = r.BillingAddress.StreetName;
```

You will need two usings:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
```

I have found this approach to be very useful in dealing with large complex `XML` files.  Mapping the `XML` structure to a `class`, then allows you to program the components in (to my mind) a much more natural OOP fashion.