# XDocument just reads the first title?

Tags: c#, xml

I need to parse xml but my code just parses one title not all.
How can I parse  part ?

This is my code:

```
CustomResponse itemCustom = new CustomResponse ();

XDocument response = XDocument.Parse(responseXml);
XElement rootElement = response.Root;

foreach (XElement sellResponse in rootElement.Elements())
{
     itemCustom .ErrorCode = sellResponse.Element("ErrorCode").Value;
     itemCustom .ErrorMessage = sellResponse.Element("ErrorMessage").Value;
     itemCustom .CustomerID= sellResponse.Element("CustomerID").Value;
     itemCustom .CustomerType= sellResponse.Element("CustomerType").Value;
}
```

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TINS_XML_DATA>
<Header>
    <ErrorCode>WAATS</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorMessage>UTL</ErrorMessage>
</Header>
<Customer>
    <CustomerID>UTL11111111111111111111</CustomerID>
    <CustomerType>NSell</CustomerType>
</Customer>
</TINS_XML_DATA>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding children of a specific parent tag in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59282599/finding-children-of-a-specific-parent-tag-in-xml)

Comment: what portion do you want to parse from your XML ?

Comment: Add more details to your question. What do you expect to happen from the code you provided?

Comment: I need to all of them but now just read first tag errorcode and errormessage

Comment: I'd expect that code to throw a `NullReferenceException`, because it will try to find the `CustomerID` element within `Header`, which doesn't exist - then dereference it with the `Value` property. You don't have all those four subelements within the same parent element, so you shouldn't expect to be able to access them all from the same element.

Comment: I understand, I should read different tag, but what can I use?

Comment: Well you've already got an answer which looks like it should work, but which you say doesn't. It's hard to help more with only snippets of code. If you could provide a [mcve] it would be easier to test any attempt at answering. I would *expect* you to not need to loop at all - just get the `Header` element and obtain the `ErrorCode` and `ErrorMessage` from that, then get the `Customer` element and get the `CustomerID` and `CustomerType` from that. Once you've provided a complete example, I can easily adapt it to show what I mean.

Comment: I understand  and solved my problem thank you  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
           foreach (XElement sellResponse in rootElement.Elements())
            {
                if (sellResponse.Name == "Header")
                {
                    itemCustom.ErrorCode = sellResponse.Element("ErrorCode").Value;
                    itemCustom.ErrorMessage = sellResponse.Element("ErrorMessage").Value;
                }
                else if (sellResponse.Name == "Customer")
                {
                    itemCustom.CustomerID = sellResponse.Element("CustomerID").Value;
                    itemCustom.CustomerType = sellResponse.Element("CustomerType").Value;
                }
            }
```

Update: You could also use XPath to find required elements as like below:

```
var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xml);

var errorMessage = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ErrorMessage")[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: I've tried but problem is sellResponse because my data all come rootElement.Elements but sellResponse just accept <Header> tag and Customer tag disappear this is my problem

Comment: @YilmazFurkan, I have updated my answer. please check.

Comment: Since you use foreach loop, on first iteration you will get <Header> element and in the second iteration you will get <Customer> tag. Hope it helps!

Comment: My problem still hear but ı thınk  understand what can ı do thank you for help

Comment: You are update ıts correct solved my problem thank you for help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my solved:

```
            var xDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xDoc.LoadXml(responseXml);

        itemSell.ErrorCode = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ErrorCode")[0].InnerText;
        itemSell.ErrorMessage = xDoc.SelectNodes("//ErrorMessage")[0].InnerText;
        itemSell.CustomerID= xDoc.SelectNodes("//CustomerID")[0].InnerText;
```